# Tensor Analysis and SR

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus

I'm looking for a textbook that covers, at least for a large part, special relativity with tensors/a geometrical approach. Most textbooks I have found develop tensors for the purposes of GR; I'd like a book that goes through this exercise for the purposes of understanding SR. I'll then feel more comfortable moving on with the GR bit.

Ideally, the textbook/resource will first cover tensors, and then move on to discuss tensor analysis in SR.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one very accessible ["Introduction to Tensor Calculus"](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf) intended as "an explanation about tensor calculus for students of physics and engineering with a basic knowledge of linear algebra."

It's central idea is that "In classical linear algebra one deals with vectors and matrices. Tensors are generalisations of vectors and matrices." Starting from an intuitive introduction to covariant and contravariant vectors, it covers everything one usually needs for a good working knowledge of tensors and their properties, including tensor calculus, the covariant derivative, and an Appendix on tensors in Special Relativity.