# Resource recommendations for learning tensor calculus

Tags: tensor-calculus, resource-recommendations

I am having trouble understanding tensor calculus can anyone please suggest some good books or lecture series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learn about tensors for physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386103/168783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna check **Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity** by Sean Carroll. The first chapter treats elements of tensor calculus from a physics point of view. Most of General relativity courses contain material on this subject in their first chapters.